# Collect Feedback Workflow for most recent minor draft ONLY

Tags: workflow, document-library, document, tasks, workflow-activity

I am new to SharePoint and I am looking to create a Collect Feedback workflow. My goal is to have an automatic workflow that triggers any time a new document is added to my Document Library, but I want the task to only be linked to the most recent minor draft (it often takes a while before the document can be reviewed, and sometimes I need to make small revisions to the uploaded documents). Additionally, I want the task to be created without a due date and I want it assigned to a manager who can then reassign it (with a due date) to whoever they want to review the document.

As I understand it, I can create an automatic workflow assigned to the manager that triggers when a new document is added to the library, and the manager will be able to re-assign/delegate the task. So far so good. But is it possible to only trigger the workflow the first time a new minor draft is added/created (to avoid duplicate tasks for the same document) *and* to link the task to the most recent minor draft so that the correct version is reviewed?

Also, if I set minor versions to only be visible to users with Edit permissions, can they still be reviewed by users who *DON'T* have Edit permissions?